# Swift Api Key Authentication

Tags: swift, api

I'm trying to make a simple get request for using Zomato's API to get JSON data. I have an API Key but I'm not sure how to use it in my normal NSURLSession call. I don't have a username or password to provide, just an 32 char API key.

The curl command is given as:

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "user_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_id=280&entity_type=city&count=5&cuisines=55"
```

My request code is here:

```
        let url = NSURL(string: myURL)!
        let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        //add api key to header somewhere here?

        let myQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in

            //I have some error handling here


                var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as! NSDictionary
                let myArray:NSArray = jsonResult["restaurants"] as! NSArray
        })
        myQuery.resume()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSession/sharedSession) for `NSURLSession.sharedSession()` says:

> In other words, if you’re doing *anything* with caches, cookies, authentication, or custom networking protocols, you should probably be using a custom session instead of the shared session.

You can create your own custom session and include your headers as follows:

```
let url = NSURL(string: myURL)!

let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = [
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "user_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
]

let urlSession = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

let myQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {
    data, response, error -> Void in
    /* ... */
})
myQuery.resume()
```

Comment: Thank you, answered my question.